# Wrong View Option Menu

Tags: android, list, view, optionmenu

I followed the steps to create option menu in Android project following this link [Here](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/01/creating-option-menu-in-android.html)

But after applying it to my project instead of option menu appearing Vertically (4 rows ), it appeared Horizontally ( 4 Items divided by 2 Rows )
What could be the problem here is my code

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
              switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.Settings:
                        // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                  Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen3);
                         return true;   

              case R.id.Verify:
                         // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                        Intent nextScreen4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Verify.class);
                        startActivity(nextScreen4);
                         return true;

               case R.id.callInfo:
                //   startActivity(new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).setData(getIntent().getData()));                        // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                                              return true;

              case R.id.email:
                                             // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                                               return true;

                default:
                                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }
```

Comment: what version of android are you testing this in? it looks like that tutorial was on a 4.0+ phone, if you're on a 2.x version it will look like you described.

Comment: version 4.3 any other possible issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of android you are targeting in your AndroidManifest.xml

It has to be equal or above Honeycomb's API version (11). Ideally you'll be targeting the latest version of Android (KitKat is 19).

See the line in your manifest that is

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And make sure that targetSdkVersion is at least 11.